# pymongo bson.code pass in variable

Tags: mongodb, scope, mapreduce, pymongo

I'm using pymongo's map_reduce framework for extracting some data out from mongodb. This is how my data look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566f570e3816dc2fe631db4f"),
    "property_id" : 5594.0000000000000000,
    "reservation_id" : "2544430.1",
    "updated" : ISODate("2015-12-15T02:04:33.000Z"),
    "offer_list" : {
        "68799" : {
            "pitched" : "no",
            "accepted" : "no"
        },
        "68801" : {
            "pitched" : "no",
            "accepted" : "no"
        }
    },
    "status" : "awarded",
    "comments" : "",
    "agent_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "created" : ISODate("2015-12-14T23:55:52.000Z")
}
```

I will need to get all record counts for each agent after some date using pymongo.

The mapper function would look like:

```
mapper = Code("""function(){
        if(this.created>start_date){
             emit(this.agent_id, 1); 
        })
```

in which start_date would be a variable passed in from python code.

By reading the document I think the scope should be set but I could not find any documentation on how to do that. I knew nothing about javascript. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you this you need `map_reduce`? Can you show the expected result?

Comment: expected output would be {agent_id:1, count:12} which indicates there are 12 records for the agent since start_date

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed using the query keyword.

```
collection.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "myresults", query={"created":{"$gte":start_date, "$lt":end_date}})
```